# like button not doing anything, cant tell what the problem is

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I want users to be able to like my post so I implemented here. here's my code. It doesn't give any error which is frustrating.

```
models.py

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


views.py

    def like(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = request.user # bring login user
            post_pk = request.POST.get('pk', None)
            post = Post.objects.get(pk = post_pk) #bring the post object.

            if post.likes.filter(id = user.id).exists(): #if exit
                post.likes.remove(user) #likes deleted.
                message = 'You disliked this'
            else:
                post.likes.add(user)
                message = 'You liked this'

        context = {'likes_count' : post.total_likes, 'message' : message}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='community-home'),

    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/new',views.comment_new, name='comment_new'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/edit',views.comment_edit, name='comment_edit'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/delete',views.comment_delete, name='comment_delete'),
    path('like/', views.like, name='like'),
```

my html

```
<input type="button" class="like" name="{{ memo.id }}" value="Like">
      <p id="count{{ memo.id }}">count : {{ memo.total_likes }}</p>



<script type="text/javascript">
  for(i = 0; i < $(".writer_name").length; i++){
    if($("#user_name").text() == $(".writer_name")[i].innerHTML){
      $("#control_id"+i).removeClass("hidden");
    }
  }


$('.like').click(function(){
  var pk = $(this).attr('name') 
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: "{% url 'like' %}", 
      data: {'pk': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, 
      dataType: "json", 


      success: function(response){ 
        id = $(this).attr('name')
        $('#count'+ pk).html("count : "+ response.likes_count);
        alert(response.message);
        alert("likes :" + response.likes_count);
      },
      error:function(request,status,error){
        alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
      }
  });
})
</script>
```

I'm not sure if my ajax is wrong or my python is wrong. but to me the logic here makes sense. if anyone can tell what the problem is I would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Let's start with some very basic debugging. What do you see in your Python terminal when the Like button is clicked? Does it show a request to your `like` endpoint? (If not, then this is a JS problem making the request never fire.) If so, what is the response code? What does your browser Network tab show about the response? etc etc. All things you could easily do yourself to narrow down the source of the problem before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jquery, before using it you must wrap code inside:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def like(request):
        response_json = request.POST
        response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
        data = json.loads(response_json)
        post = Post.objects.get(pk =data['pk'])
        if post.likes.filter(id = user.id).exists(): #if exit
            post.likes.remove(user) #likes deleted.
            message = 'You disliked this'
        else:
            post.likes.add(user)
            message = 'You liked this'

        context = {'likes_count' : post.total_likes, 'message' : message}
        return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)
```

try like this. You are sending a JSON datatype so python has to interpret it as so.